# How to find the difference between elements, ignoring NA values

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to find the difference between datetimes in a pandas dataframe column, however many of the entries within the column are NA values.  An Example dataset:

```
Dates = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '2019-12-11', np.nan, '2019-12-14', np.nan, np.nan, '2019-12-20', '2019-12-23'])
```

My goal is to find the time interval between each listed date, ignoring however many null values fall between the dates, i.e. How many days passed between '2019-12-20', and '2019-12-14' while ignoring the 2 NA values in between, and ultimately will append that information to a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter out the nan then use `diff`

```py
s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '2019-12-11', np.nan, '2019-12-14', np.nan, np.nan, '2019-12-20', '2019-12-23'])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)

s[~s.isna()].diff()

# 3      NaT
# 5   3 days
# 8   6 days
# 9   3 days
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

another option would be

```py
s.ffill().diff()

# 0      NaT
# 1      NaT
# 2      NaT
# 3      NaT
# 4   0 days
# 5   3 days
# 6   0 days
# 7   0 days
# 8   6 days
# 9   3 days
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```